# Expecting many records from my query. I only get one

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, view

I have a query where I am trying to sum values from two other tables into a view.
The parent table is called Limit.A Limit has many Allocations. And many Extensions.(These are the 2 tables I am trying to sum into my view). Each record also has a source entity. When I run this query, I only get one record or Source entity when I expect many more. Here is my query:

```
    Select distinct *,
convert(varchar(100), p.Limit )  AS keyfield
    from

    (

    select distinct
    se.Oid as SourceEntity, 
    l.oid as Limit ,
    SUM(la.ARLimit) AS LAARLimit,
    SUM(la.MTMLimit) AS LAMTMLimit,
   SUM(la.Volume) AS LAMaxVolume,
   SUM(la.MaxTenor) AS LAMaxTenor,
   SUM(le.ARLimit) AS LEARLimit, 
   SUM(le.MTMLimit) AS LEMTMLimit, 
  SUM(le.Volume) AS LEMAxVolume, 
SUM(le.MaxTenor) AS LEMaxTenor, SUM(la.ARLimit) + SUM(le.ARLimit) AS [ARLimit], 
SUM(la.MTMLimit) + SUM(le.MTMLimit) AS [MTMLimit], 
SUM(la.Volume) + SUM (le.Volume) AS [Volume], 
SUM(la.MaxTenor) + SUM(le.MaxTenor) AS [MaxTenor]
from limit l
left join limitallocation la
    on l.oid = la.limit
    left join limitextension le
    on l.oid = le.limit
    left join 
dbo.SourceEntity as se on la.SourceEntity = se.oid and le.SourceEntity = se.Oid
where se.oid is not null
GROUP BY l.Oid,se.Oid) as p
```

I only get One Source entity with the allocations and extensions calculating correctly for each Limit. But I expect many more Source Entities.

Comment: You will probably need to provide table structure and test data.

Comment: What's the best way to do that in this forum? Pictures?

Comment: The best would be to use http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Check you left join (SourceEntity) and your where clause.  If a where clause references a field from the left join table, the LEFT JOIN in essence becomes a JOIN.

Comment: By the way, in the inner query, I would suggest removing the DISTINCT.  Unless you are truly worried about a row with identical SourceEntry,Limit, and 12 sums...

Comment: Is the relationship between `la` and `le` and `se` really 1-1?  If `la` has a source and `le` has a source, but ~~not~~ the same source, then your construct is wrong: you need two left joins, say `sela` and `sele`

Comment: Please format you code. This is next to unreadable.